# activityindicatorview before segue, stopping after new view finishes view did load

Tags: ios, segue, uiactivityindicatorview

I have two views in this scenario, tableviewA and tableViewB.
When I click on a table row cell in ViewA, I want to start the spinning indicator.

as of now when I hit the cell, it performs a segue into ViewB.
Then in ViewDidLoad in ViewB, it downloads long running operation, then loads new tableview cells.
After the tableviewB loads I want to turn off the spinning indicator in ViewA.

So far I put the indicator in viewA like so

ViewA

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.activityView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 35.0, 35.0);
self.activityView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:self.activityView];


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self.activityView startAnimating];
```

ViewB

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//LONG RUNNING OPERATION HERE
```

so obviously I'm doing something wrong.  What happens now, is I only see the indicator turn on in ViewA after the long running operation in viewB finishes.
The indictor turns on for a split second, then switches the view.

any ideas on the correct way to do this?

Comment: try adding an activityView to viewB?

Comment: but viewB does not actually pop up until after the long running operation finishes.  Guess because its in the viewDidLoad.    will that still work?

Comment: good UX practice is to not interrupt the UI. you should do the long running operation in a background thread and that should let you navigate to viewB and show the activityView there